# PHP XML converter response

Tags: php, xml

im quite new on `XML`, i am currently work in PHP and i have a request to other server which normaly and always return the callback with `XML`

In any case i would not talk about how i get the response, but how to convert the `XML` reponse.

They are two type of the `XML` response, we could call it as `$response`

**first :**

```
<BASEELEMENT SCHEMA="RESULT" METHOD="ADD-MBX">
   <RETURN_VALUE>4</RETURN_VALUE>
   <ERROR_DESCRIPTION>
      <![CDATA[Error (7004): Login name already exists. Please use another login name.]]>
   </ERROR_DESCRIPTION> 
</BASEELEMENT>
```

and the **second** one is :

```
<baseelement schema="TIMEOUT" method="ADD-MBX"></baseelement>
```

i have searched and i got how to convert the xml reponse to obejct or array, which is

```
$response = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

after convert :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#256 (3) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["SCHEMA"]=>
    string(6) "RESULT"
    ["METHOD"]=>
    string(7) "ADD-MBX"
  }
  ["RETURN_VALUE"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["ERROR_DESCRIPTION"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#257 (0) {
  }
}
```

as we can see the `ERROR_DESCRIPTION` become `0`.

So i would like to ask, is there any `xml converter` else `simplexml_load_string()` or `new \SimpleXMLElement()`

i cant use that function because i could not get the `ERROR_DESCRIPTION`

thank you :)

Comment: How exactly did you try to read the `ERROR_DESCRIPTION`?

Comment: using `rest client`, or echo `"<pre>" var_dump() `, with echo pre vardump, the xml was hide, so i am using inspect element to see the xml response @ThW

Answer (score 0):

Loading it as you are with -

```
$response = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

You can fetch the value quite simply as...

```
echo (string)($response->ERROR_DESCRIPTION).PHP_EOL;
```

If you want the full content (as in an XML version)...

```
echo $response->ERROR_DESCRIPTION->asXML().PHP_EOL;
```

Using XPath, you can fetch the values by...

```
echo (string)$response->xpath("//ERROR_DESCRIPTION")[0].PHP_EOL;
```

The output you are seeing shows that ERROR_DESCRIPTION is an object of SimpleXMLElement type, not that it isn't loaded.